# Работа с массивами в Postgresql

Tags: массивы, postgresql, оптимизация

Мне необходимо динамически составлять SQL запрос.

```
SELECT
    s.* ,
    ARRAY(
        SELECT 
            stt.tag_id 
        FROM subscriber_to_tag stt 
        WHERE 
            stt.channel_id = s.channel_id 
            stt.subscriber_id = s.subscriber_id
    ) as test 
FROM s
WHERE 1 in test AND 2 in test AND 3 in test
```

Запрос выдаёт ошибку

```
     ERROR:  syntax error at or near "test"
     LINE 2: ... s.subscriber_id) as test FROM subscribers s WHERE 1 in test
```

Вот этих цифр, - 1,2,3, - может быть много, и, чтобы постоянно не делать select, я хочу сохранить это в переменную и проверять вхождение.

Есть идеи как это сделать по-умному?

Answer (score 0):

Соберите из чисел 1, 2, 3... и какие там надо массив и используйте оператор `<@` **содержится в** для него и массива из подзапроса. [Мануал](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/functions-array)

Примечание: Вы не можете обращаться к колонкам результата из выражения WHERE, поскольку на момент фильтрации строк WHERE колонки результата ещё не существуют. Загоните создание массива из подзапроса ещё внутрь подзапроса в таком виде:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(
               SELECT t.col
               FROM (
                      SELECT 1 AS col
                      UNION
                      SELECT 2
                      UNION
                      SELECT 3
                    ) t
           ) AS ccol
  ) tt
  WHERE ARRAY[1, 2] <@ (ccol) ; --только строки с 1 И 2
```